# Proving multiplying a 2nd degree term by a conditionally convergent series converges absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I was asked to prove that if $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally $\Rightarrow$ $\sum n^2 a_n$ diverges. The proof prompt hints at using proof by contradiction. So far, I have shown that

$a_n$ converges conditionally, then $a_n \rightarrow 0$, then $n^2 a_n \rightarrow 0$ regardless of the $n$. However, I don't think this is sufficient to imply the summation converges as well.

Comment: If the sum of a_n converges conditionally, it need not be the case that n^2*a_n goes to 0. Take, for instance, the alternating harmonic series.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose to the contrary that $\sum n^2a_n$ converges. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2|a_n|=0$. Thus if $n$ is large enough, then $n^2|a_n|\lt 1$.

It follows that if $n$ is large enough then $|a_n|\lt \frac{1}{n^2}$, and therefore by *Comparison* $\sum|a_n|$ converges, contradicting the fact that $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally.  For since $\sum a_n$ converges *conditionally*, $\sum|a_n|$ diverges.

Comment: I understand the beginning and the final premises. However, the part that I have is the justification that for large $n$, $n^2 |a_n|$ < 1

Comment: So it is clear to you that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2|a_n|=0$. By the definition of limit, for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|n^2|a_n|-0|\lt \epsilon$, or equivalently $0\le n^2a_n\lt \epsilon$. Choose $\epsilon=1$. We conclude that there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $0\le n^2|a_n|\lt 1$.

Comment: @GooshiRoy: if a series is conditionally convergent, its general term is infinitesimal, hence by assuming that $\sum n^2 a_n < \infty$ we have that for any $n$ big enough $|n^2 a_n|<1$ holds.

Comment: @Jack Is it common terminology in Italian textbooks to refer to sequences converging to zero as "infinitesimal" (or perhaps *successione infinitesima*)?  We frequently use *null* and "infinitesimal" I've only seen very rarely.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: all right, "infinitesimal" to me is just "converging to zero".